# Display User First name on main form when login with username

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with table name tbl_login.

Fields in the table include:
FirstName, LastName, UserName & Password.

Am able to login to open my main form successfully.

Now my issue is, I will like to let the users First name be displayed when logged in.

Eg. if Samson is the FirstName and  Sam is the UserName, when I log in with Sam, Samson should be displayed on my main form as the current active user.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You must preserve the login name to a variable then use `DLOOKUP("[FirstName]","[tbl_login]","[UserName= '" & VariableName & "'")`.

Comment: Alright Sir. let me give it a try and get back to you

Comment: I created a textbox. The I put these codes in the control Source.  
#DLOOKUP("[FirstName]","[tbl_login]","[UserName= '" & [StrUserName] &  "'").               But I get #Name? after login. Please I need help

Comment: What is `[StrUserName]` here?